# Rest endpoint with variable search criteria

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am writing a Spring Boot rest endpoint that returns data from an Oracle database of 2 tables. I want to allow the client to vary their query parameters. For example, to query on just firstName, just lastName, firstName + lastName, or DOB etc. I want to make it flexible. I don't want to write multiple endpoints to cater for many query permutations; I'd like to write one endpoint with some sort of variable criteria.

I know I can just append to query string in a GET request, e.g. /find?firstName=Joe, lastName=Bloggs, but I'd prefer not to have my parameters in the url (mabe this is the only way?)

I've seen jakarta.persistence.CriteriaBuilder getCriteriaBuilder() used but it seems complicated.

Are there any modern libraries that cater for this design pattern?

Comment: Consider RSQL for REST-based filter or GraphQL. It also depends on the number of fields you want to filter by.